# Having hosting error

Tags: magento2, cron, index, hosting

I have read a lot and tried a lot but I keep getting the message:

One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.

And this only count for Catalog Search, if I try in SSH I get this error:

```
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title> </head>
<body> 
   <h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
  <p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for this
URL.</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe contact your hosting provider. Or check if your server meets the magneto requirements. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

It does have the requirements... for the rest all is working just not this part what also makes it not possible for seeing the products or category in the front page.

Comment: I have now installed elastichsearch what was indeed missing... now I get a new error that is:

Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [text] declared on field [_search]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [text] declared on field [_search]"},"status":400}